# Mapping to an internal type with AutoMapper for Silverlight

Tags: automapper

How do I configure my application so AutoMapper can map to internal types and/or properties in Silverlight 5?  For example, I have the following type:

```
internal class SomeInfo
{
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

I try to call Mapper.DynamicMap with this type as the destination and I receive the following error at runtime:

> Attempt by security transparent method
>   'DynamicClass.SetValue(System.Object, System.Object)' to access
>   security critical type 'Acme.SomeInfo' failed.

I've tried instantiating the class first, then passing the instance to DynamicMap as well as changing the class scope to public with an internal setter for the property.  I've also marked the class with the [SecuritySafeCritical] attribute.  All of these tests resulted in the same error message.

The only way I've been able to get past this is to completely expose the class with public scope and public setters.  This is, of course, a problem as I am developing a class library that will be used by other developers and using "internal" scope is a deliberate strategy to hide implementations details as well as make sure code is used only as intended (following the no public setters concept from DDD and CQRS).

That said, what can I do to make it so AutoMapper can work with internal types and/or properties?

(Note: The class library is built for SL5 and used in client apps configured to run out-of-browser with elevated trust.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a Silverlight limitation - it does not allow reflection on private/protected/internal members from outside assemblies, see:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc(VS.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/stfy7tfc%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Simply put - AutoMapper can't access internal members of your assembly.

Comment: What about using the InternalsVisibleTo attribute in my assembly to grant AutoMapper access to my internal types?  It appears that this allows me to have an internal constructor but I still can't have internal setters on my properties.  Still not sure I understand why I can Import internal properties in SL but AutoMapper can't set them.